# No module named PIL in heroku though it is installed

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library, virtual-environment

I have been trying to deploy a Django application on Heroku.

**Some background** - I hadn't used virtual environment while building the application but while deploying it, I had to use it. I'm following this tutorial for deployment. https://medium.com/agatha-codes/9-straightforward-steps-for-deploying-your-django-app-with-heroku-82b952652fb4
Now I'm stuck in step-6. After creating a virtual environment I have freezed the dependencies into `requirements.txt`.

But when I open the deployed URL it says

```
ImportError at /
No module named PIL
```

though Pillow has been installed, it is there in requirements.txt and runs fine when hosted on a local server.

This is my requirements.txt.

```
certifi==2018.4.16
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.14
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
packaging==17.1
Pillow==5.2.0
pip-review==1.0
pipenv==2018.7.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2018.5
six==1.11.0
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: did you try `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: Yes, this is there in my code, views.py.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku? Access your application and manually run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then turn the application off and back on again.

I had this problem before, this step solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in your view

```
import PIL
```

do this

```
import Image
```

Comment: It gives No module named Image.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this issue by installing 'Pillow'... just try `pip/pip3 install Pillow` and add it to your requirements.txt file.