# templates cannot be found when virtual environment is activated

Tags: python, html, django, heroku

I am facing a rather peculiar problem. I have built a Django application and only while deploying it, I created a virtual environment(I didn't use virtual environment while building and testing it locally). Now when virtual environment is activated and also when deactivated, the HTML templates cannot be found. Below is the screenshot.

[image: 1]]

Seeing this statement,

```
Python Executable: /home/shadowsaint/Programs/Django/zoomtail/venv/bin/python
```

I went back to terminal and typed `which python` command. For that it shows

```
/home/shadowsaint/Programs/Django/zoomtail/venv/bin/python
```

Now when I deactivate virtual environment also the `which python` command gives the same thing.

But when I delete the `venv` file, and run `which python` it gives,

```
/usr/bin/python
```

And now the application runs fine, i.e., the HTML templates are being found.

I have three questions here.

1. When I activate `venv`, the python used from `venv/bin` is fine. But even when I deactivate virtual environment why the same `python` is being used?
2. What does python package(both the versions are same) have to do with templates being found?
3. Is the underlying principle here the same as that in here too - [No module named PIL in heroku though it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188975/no-module-named-pil-in-heroku-though-it-is-installed/51193194#51193194)

Comment: Dunno if it about your python, maybe is about how configured your project are

Comment: have you installed all requiriments in your virtualenv? can you pip freeze it and post?

Comment: They trying to find your template at your python installation or in ir venv... but your templates should be at your django project... maybe its missconfiguration of your django

Comment: I have given the requirements.txt in the question mentioned in 3.

Comment: How do I make this misconfiguration right?

Comment: Looks like your Heroku have a misconfiguration... you cant find import in the other post... and now you cant find your template... try run again requirements with your vm active, set up your Heroku to use your VM and restart your app

Answer (score 0):

**You have a misconfiguration at your Heroku environment**, first check if your requirements was installed, use shell (python manage.py shell) and try import some of them to see if they throw errors... if passes ok then try to access any url from your project... if template breaks maybe the problem is in your **Template_DIR at your settings**

Obs.: check if your django commands like shell, migrate... works when running heroku run bash with your venv activated

Try follow some of this steps:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

Verify in project `settings.py` that `INSTALLED_APPS` list actually contains your app name.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'your app',
 'django.contrib...'
 .....
```