# PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH for Django in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, configuration, constants

This is a follow-up question for this.
[No module named PIL in heroku though it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188975/no-module-named-pil-in-heroku-though-it-is-installed?noredirect=1#comment89427027_51188975)

I got help from Heroku website here. https://help.heroku.com/BWJ7QYTF/why-am-i-seeing-importerror-no-module-named-site-when-deploying-a-python-app

But from the terminal, when I type `heroku config` I only get the `DATABASE_URL`. How do I set these variables?

Comment: That page from the Heroku docs explicitly says you *don't* want to set them, and that you should unset them if they are set. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Oh okay. Yes, thanks.